# Marginal density for joint pdf of multiple random variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, density-function, marginal-probability

I have the joint pdf $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=12x_2 \;\mathrm f \mathrm o \mathrm r \; 0<x_3<x_2<x_1<1,$ and $0$ elsewhere. I want to find the marginal pdf $f_{x_3}(x_3)$.

I know that to do this I will integrate out $x_1$ and $x_2$, and I have tried setting up the integral as
$\int_{x_3}^{1} \int_{x_2}^{1} 12x_2 \;dx_1dx_2$, which yields $4x_3^3 -6x_3^2+2$. This can't be correct since it takes on values greater than one on the interval $(0,1)$.

I can't seem to find where I made a mistake, so if someone could help me understand where I went wrong it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your limits are wrong, notice that $x_2$ is bounded from above by $x_1$.

Comment: I must still be misunderstanding something. Using the new limits with the following setup $\int_{x_3}^{1} \int_{x_3}^{x_1} 12x_2 \;dx_2dx_1$ I still end up with the above result. I'm assuming it's another limit error?

Comment: @sk13 Your limits are still wrong, $x_1>x_2$. Also I don't believe that your pdf is normalized.